# Equation of motion for explicit time dependent potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

What is the equation of motion for a single scalar field, which has a   Lagrangian density in which the potential explicitly depends on time? For example: $$U(\phi,t)=\frac{1}{2}\phi^2 - \frac{1}{3} e^{t/T}\phi^3 + \frac{1}{8}\phi^4$$ where $T$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a Klein-Gordon equation with a RHS.
Explicitly, the E-L equation for a scalar field is
$$\partial_{\mu} {\partial {\mathcal L} \over \partial \phi_{,\mu}} - {\partial {\mathcal L} \over \partial \phi} = 0$$
so for your potential we have
$$\square \phi + \phi - e^{t/T} \phi^2 + {1 \over 2} \phi^3 = 0$$

Comment: Can u derive these equation from the first principle of variation of action.My point is that why coefficient in cubic phi term not differentiated with respect to time?

Comment: @Rakesh Here's the derivation: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/the-euler-lagrange-equation-in-special-relativity/1698#1698 I hope it also clarifies to you why one does not differentiate that term; the reason is no different from classical mechanics though: just take a Lagrangian $L = T - V(t)$ and see for yourself...

Comment: @Rakesh: For a slightly more interesting model with explicit time dependence, consider moving the factor $e^{t/T}$ to instead multiplying the kinetic term...